# Can't configure ionic v1 existing project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, moodle-mobile

I get a codebase of existing ionic old project with below dependency versions. I can't able to configure or run the project .

I have clone the project from git and run npm install . its showing below error.

> npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms npm timing
>   stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 24222ms npm verb stack Error:
>   premature close npm verb stack     at PassThrough.onclose
>   (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:47:67) npm verb stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:203:15) npm verb
>   stack     at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:8) npm verb
>   stack     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) npm verb cwd
>   /Users/apple/Documents/code
>   /Source/SourceCode/prama-select-user-type-3c9d5653606bf079b7c2b60c51bd52b2ccf5967a/codebase/moodleapp npm verb Darwin 18.6.0 npm verb argv
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.18.0/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/npm" "install" "--verbose" npm verb node
>   v10.18.0 npm verb npm  v6.13.4 npm ERR! premature close npm verb exit
>   [ 1, true ] npm timing npm Completed in 24694ms

Version Information:

`Ionic: 2.2.1
Cordova: 7.1.0
Cordova Android platform: 8.0.0
Node: 10.16.0
NPM: 6.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by looking if your network has any proxies, that is prohibiting the download process. Some company's network has a firewall enabled, which can be causing the issue for you. You can switch to an un-secure network (like a hotspot from your mobile network) and that should work for you.

Also you can try running this in your CLI

```
> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then try again.

Comment: I follow your instructions but now getthing this error . npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm ERR! premature close

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2020-01-10T09_27_45_228Z-debug.log

Comment: Npm install is still not working but project get run by yarn install. After yarn install i can't able to add platform . COMMAND :- ionic cordova  platform add android@8.0.0
ERROR :- ionic[42623]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:635:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.                                                                                          and npm install giving the same error.